# "sudo yum install php55w-mysqlnd" conflict

Tags: php, mysql, centos, mysqlnd

I can't install the package php55w-mysqlnd using the command

```
sudo yum install  php55w-mysqlnd
```

It always give me the error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, replace
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.vastspace.net
 * epel: mirror.smartmedia.net.id
 * extras: mirror.vastspace.net
 * updates: mirror.vastspace.net
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php55w-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.5.29-1.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php55w-mysql-5.5.29-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php55w-mysqlnd
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php55w-mysql conflicts with php55w-mysqlnd-5.5.29-1.w6.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

To check if php55w-mysqlnd is already installed, I use the command:

```
yum list installed | grep php
```

And the result is:

```
php-ZendFramework.noarch                      1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-ZendFramework-Auth-Adapter-Ldap.noarch    1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-ZendFramework-Cache-Backend-Libmemcached.noarch
php-ZendFramework-Cache-Backend-Memcached.noarch
php-ZendFramework-Captcha.noarch              1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Firebird.noarch  1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Mysqli.noarch    1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Pdo.noarch       1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Pdo-Mssql.noarch 1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Pdo-Mysql.noarch 1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Pdo-Pgsql.noarch 1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-ZendFramework-Dojo.noarch                 1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-ZendFramework-Feed.noarch                 1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-ZendFramework-Ldap.noarch                 1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-ZendFramework-Pdf.noarch                  1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-ZendFramework-Search-Lucene.noarch        1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-ZendFramework-Serializer-Adapter-Igbinary.noarch
php-ZendFramework-Services.noarch             1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-ZendFramework-Soap.noarch                 1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-ZendFramework-extras.noarch               1.12.13-1.el6            @epel    
php-php-gettext.noarch                        1.0.11-3.el6             @epel    
php55w.x86_64                                 5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
php55w-bcmath.x86_64                          5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
php55w-cli.x86_64                             5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
php55w-common.x86_64                          5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
php55w-gd.x86_64                              5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
php55w-interbase.x86_64                       5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
php55w-ldap.x86_64                            5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
php55w-mbstring.x86_64                        5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
php55w-mcrypt.x86_64                          5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
php55w-mssql.x86_64                           5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
php55w-mysql.x86_64                           5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
php55w-opcache.x86_64                         5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
php55w-pdo.x86_64                             5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
php55w-pear.noarch                            1:1.9.4-7.w6             @webtatic
php55w-pecl-igbinary.x86_64                   1.2.1-2.w6               @webtatic
php55w-pecl-memcache.x86_64                   3.0.8-2.w6               @webtatic
php55w-pecl-memcached.x86_64                  2.2.0-2.w6               @webtatic
php55w-pgsql.x86_64                           5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
php55w-process.x86_64                         5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
php55w-soap.x86_64                            5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
php55w-xml.x86_64                             5.5.29-1.w6              @webtatic
```

Can anyone help me what I'm missing here?

Comment: What does `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` output?

Comment: It outputs nothing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php55w-mysql` and `php55w-mysqlnd` are two mysql packages which provide the same thing, that's why they are conflicting.

`php55w-mysql` provides php-mysqli, php_database

`php55w-mysqlnd` provides  php-mysqli, php_database

You should install only either one.

Comment: Oh I see.. If I uninstall php55w-mysql, will it affect any data in my database?

Comment: No, it will not delete your database files. It is designed in a way that it doesn't touch the user data, it will only delete the package files. You will be able to access your database files. Just to be sure nothing's changed in the recent versions, you can make a backup of your /var/lib/mysql/ folder which contains your database files.

Comment: Noted. I will try now. Will get back to you with the result. Thanks!