# Processing Conflict: php55w-mysql-5.5.30-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts php55w-mysqlnd

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

php 5.5.30; mysql 5.6.10

I'm trying to execute a prepared statement:

```
$stmt->execute ();
$result = $stmt->get_result ();
```

But I get:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()`

I understand that this function required Mysqlnd - so I did

```
# yum install php-mysqlnd
```

but I get:

```
---> Package php55w-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.5.30-2.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php55w-mysql-5.5.30-2.w6.x86_64 conflicts php55w-mysqlnd
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php55w-mysql conflicts with php55w-mysqlnd-5.5.30-2.w6.x86_64
```

for reference:

```
# yum list installed | grep php
php55w.x86_64                        5.5.30-2.w6                @webtatic       
php55w-cli.x86_64                    5.5.30-2.w6                @webtatic       
php55w-common.x86_64                 5.5.30-2.w6                @webtatic       
php55w-gd.x86_64                     5.5.30-2.w6                @webtatic       
php55w-imap.x86_64                   5.5.30-2.w6                @webtatic       
php55w-mbstring.x86_64               5.5.30-2.w6                @webtatic       
php55w-mysql.x86_64                  5.5.30-2.w6                @webtatic       
php55w-pdo.x86_64                    5.5.30-2.w6                @webtatic       
php55w-xml.x86_64                    5.5.30-2.w6                @webtatic
```

How can I get around these issues?  I'd much rather use MySqli than PDO

Comment: both packages provide the same thing apparently, see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32765134/5043552. do the following and update the question with the output `php -i | grep mysqlnd` and `php -m | grep mysqlnd`

Comment: those are two different commands, run them individually

Comment: oops. Ok - both commands return nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `-mysql` package with `-mysqlnd` package

```
yum remove `php55w-mysql`
yum install `php55w-mysqlnd`
```

Comment: thanks. there are a couple of other applications running on the server, but I'll try this - I can always revert if the apps break